# Can I declare a (Flutter Modular) ModularRouter without define a route?

Tags: flutter, web

I am creating a website using Flutter with Modular and I need to create custom links for my clients. Can I create a ModularRouter without defining a RouterName?

currently I'm creating that:

```
ModularRouter(
      'customerLink',
      child: (context, args) => CheckinRouterManagerPage(),
      transition: TransitionType.noTransition,
    ),
```

I would like creating then

```
ModularRouter(
          any,
          child: (context, args) => CheckinRouterManagerPage(),
          transition: TransitionType.noTransition,
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create Dynamic Routes, in which case it would be something like this:

```
ModularRouter(
          "/customerLink/:id", // Or any other attribute that makes sense in your code.
          child: (context, args) => CheckinRouterManagerPage(args: args.params['id']),
          transition: TransitionType.noTransition,
        ),
```

Using this in the controller:

```
Modular.to.pushNamed ('/customerLink/62');
```

You can access the object you want.

Refs: [Dynamic Routes](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_modular/versions/1.2.3)